# How to add/remove objects in array using UISwitch on/off in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, uiswitch

I have added UISwitch in UITableViewCell but **How to add or remove objects from array when switch get ON/OFF.**

Here is my code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [menuArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UISwitch *switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    if ([userSession.searchedArray count] > 0)
    {
        if ([userSession.searchedArray containsObject:cell.textLabel.text])
        {
            switchview.on = YES;
        }
    }
     switchview.tag = indexPath.row;
    [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.accessoryView = switchview;

}

//Switch action

-(void)switchToggle:(id)sender
{
   UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;

    NSLog(@"tag %d",theSwitch.tag);
    NSInteger i = [sender tag];

    if (theSwitch.isOn)
    {
         NSString *str = [menuArray1 objectAtIndex:i];
         [array addObject:str];
         userSession.searchedArray = array;
         NSLog(@"SearchArray %@",userSession.searchedArray);
    }
   else
    {
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        userSession.searchedArray = array;
    }

  }
```

My **application is getting crash** when I am try to remove objects from array when UISwitch is off.

Where I am going wrong? Please suggest me the correct way to add or remove objects from array if UISwitch is on/off.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: when you are adding and removing objects from a array, don't use removeObjectAtIndex: until you are certain if the object exists at that index and is the correct object that you are trying to remove

Comment: Sounds like an **array-out-of-bounce** crash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hii  first of all check if the object is added or not.

log the array after adding the object.

```
 [array removeObject: [menuArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
```

try this.